# unknown parse error when testing function

Tags: c, parsing, parse-error

I have the function below which seems to act as it should, however when running the program through a testing program, I am given the errors: parse error: [int xSwapped = ((255 << nShift) | (255 << mShift));] and
undeclared variable `xSwapped': [return (~xSwapped & x) | nMask | mMask;]

```
int dl15(int x, int n, int m){
        // calculates shifts, create mask to shift, combine result
        // get number of bytes needed to shift, multiplying by 8
        // get Masks by shifting 0xff and shift amount
        // shift bits to required position
        // combine results

        int nShift = n<< 3;
        int mShift = m<< 3;

        int nMask = x & (255 << nShift);
        int mMask = x & (255 << mShift);
        nMask = 255 & (nMask >> nShift);
        mMask = 255 & (mMask >> mShift);
        nMask = nMask << mShift;
        mMask = mMask << nShift;

        int xSwapped = ((255 << nShift) | (255 << mShift));

        return (~xSwapped & x) | nMask | mMask;

}
```

Not certain what im missing, thank you.

Comment: Do you use MSVC (or C89 compiler)?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no, not on windows the tester uses an ANSI C compiler from the MIT CILK group

Comment: if use GCC, use `-std=c99` options. or that line  move to after `int mShift = m<< 3;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using a C compiler set to an old C standard. Prior to C99 you could not put executable statements before declarations.

You can fix this by moving the declaration of `xSwapped` to the top:

```
int nShift = n<< 3;
int mShift = m<< 3;

int nMask = x & (255 << nShift);
int mMask = x & (255 << mShift);
int xSwapped;                                   // Declaration
nMask = 255 & (nMask >> nShift);
mMask = 255 & (mMask >> mShift);
nMask = nMask << mShift;
mMask = mMask << nShift;

xSwapped = ((255 << nShift) | (255 << mShift)); // Assignment

return (~xSwapped & x) | nMask | mMask;
```